# How should I extract @angular/material css file in Angular v13?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-cli, tailwind-css

- In my Angular[v13] project, I used `@angular/material`. I also want to use `tailwindcss`.
- but `@angular/material`css is a style tag in head. so `tailwindcss` is not working.
  [image]
- Now i want to extract @angular/material css file. Or is there any way to solve this problem

Comment: use !w-4 !h-4 so it will be compiled as width:1rem !important.

Comment: I dont think removing @angular/material css file is correct way. Instead you can write custom scss .mat-icon{ @apply w-4 h-4 } which should also work

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene Thanks for your answer. `!w-4` and `@apply` is work. But this way is not very convenient.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene I dont want to remove `@angular/material` css file. I want to extract a single css file, not a style tag in html head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, be sure to [activate `important` flag](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important) on tailwindcss config, in order to automatically mark all css class with [`!important` clause](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp).

So every predefined classes of TailwindCSS will override `@angular/material` styles.

tailwind.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  important: true,
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This way is worked. But i still don't want to use `!important` everywhere

Comment: Now i used `important: '#root'`  to solve this problem.  thanks a lot !!